# Spring GS - Creating a Batch Service missing output from db query

Tags: spring-batch

I have run the complete source for [Getting Started - Creating a Batch Service](http://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/)

Knowing that the sample uses the memory-based database provided by the @EnableBatchProcessing, is the db query result expected or it will only be available if data will be persisted permanently?

After adding some debug lines, it seems that the DB query is executed first before the job gets executed. Was this the expected behavior?

Is there anything I'm missing here.

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't missing anything.  This is related to issue number 8 for that guide (https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-batch-processing/issues/8).  I just created a pull request to address this issue.  You can view the PR here (https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-batch-processing/pull/9) until it's merged.

**UPDATE**
The PR has been merged and the guid has been updated.  The new version should no longer have this issue.